# NFS Share on Centos 7 Fails to automount

Tags: centos, nfs, automounting, autofs

I have a fresh install of Centos 7. I cannot seem to auto mount an NFS share located on `192.168.254.105:/srv/nfsshare` from the Centos client.

Mounting the share manually however, works perfectly.

**/etc/auto.master** has been commented out completely to simplify the problem, save for the following line:

```
/-       /etc/auto.nfsshare
```

**/etc/auto.nfsshare**  holds the following line:

```
/tests/nfsshare       -fstype=nfs,credentials=/etc/credentials.txt    192.168.254.105:/srv/nfsshare
```

**/etc/credentials.txt** holds:

```
 user=user
 password=password
```

The expected behavior is that when I `ls -l /tests/nfsshare`, I will see a few files that my fileserver's **/srv/nfsshare** directory holds.

It does not. Instead, it shows nothing.

The logs from **sudo journalctl --unit=autofs.service** shows this when it starts (debug enabled):

```
 Nov 20 00:25:38 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Starting Automounts filesystems on demand...
 Nov 20 00:25:38 localhost.localdomain automount[21204]: Starting automounter version 5.0.7-48.el7, master map auto.master
 Nov 20 00:25:38 localhost.localdomain automount[21204]: using kernel protocol version 5.02
 Nov 20 00:25:38 localhost.localdomain automount[21204]: lookup_nss_read_master: reading master files auto.master
 Nov 20 00:25:38 localhost.localdomain automount[21204]: parse_init: parse(sun): init gathered global options: (null)
 Nov 20 00:25:38 localhost.localdomain automount[21204]: spawn_mount: mtab link detected, passing -n to mount
 Nov 20 00:25:38 localhost.localdomain automount[21204]: spawn_umount: mtab link detected, passing -n to mount
 Nov 20 00:25:38 localhost.localdomain automount[21204]: lookup_read_master: lookup(file): read entry /-
 Nov 20 00:25:38 localhost.localdomain automount[21204]: master_do_mount: mounting /-
 Nov 20 00:25:38 localhost.localdomain automount[21204]: automount_path_to_fifo: fifo name /run/autofs.fifo--
 Nov 20 00:25:38 localhost.localdomain automount[21204]: lookup_nss_read_map: reading map file /etc/auto.nfsshare
 Nov 20 00:25:38 localhost.localdomain automount[21204]: parse_init: parse(sun): init gathered global options: (null)
 Nov 20 00:25:38 localhost.localdomain automount[21204]: spawn_mount: mtab link detected, passing -n to mount
 Nov 20 00:25:38 localhost.localdomain automount[21204]: spawn_umount: mtab link detected, passing -n to mount
 Nov 20 00:25:38 localhost.localdomain automount[21204]: mounted direct on /tests/nfsshare with timeout 300, freq 75 seconds
 Nov 20 00:25:38 localhost.localdomain automount[21204]: do_mount_autofs_direct: mounted trigger /tests/nfsshare
 Nov 20 00:25:38 localhost.localdomain automount[21204]: st_ready: st_ready(): state = 0 path /-
 Nov 20 00:25:38 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Started Automounts filesystems on demand.
```

The following appears in my logs when I attempt to force mounting of the nfs share via **ls -l /tests/nfsshare**:

```
 Nov 20 00:48:05 localhost.localdomain automount[22030]: handle_packet: type = 5
 Nov 20 00:48:05 localhost.localdomain automount[22030]: handle_packet_missing_direct: token 21, name /tests/nfsshare, request pid 22057
 Nov 20 00:48:05 localhost.localdomain automount[22030]: attempting to mount entry /tests/nfsshare
 Nov 20 00:48:05 localhost.localdomain automount[22030]: lookup_mount: lookup(file): looking up /tests/nfsshare
 Nov 20 00:48:05 localhost.localdomain automount[22030]: lookup_mount: lookup(file): /tests/nfsshare -> -fstype=nfs,credentials=/etc/credenti...fsshare
 Nov 20 00:48:05 localhost.localdomain automount[22030]: parse_mount: parse(sun): expanded entry: -fstype=nfs,credentials=/etc/credentials.tx...fsshare
 Nov 20 00:48:05 localhost.localdomain automount[22030]: parse_mount: parse(sun): gathered options: fstype=nfs,credentials=/etc/credentials.txt  
 Nov 20 00:48:05 localhost.localdomain automount[22030]: [90B blob data]
 Nov 20 00:48:05 localhost.localdomain automount[22030]: dev_ioctl_send_fail: token = 21
 Nov 20 00:48:05 localhost.localdomain automount[22030]: failed to mount /tests/nfsshare
 Nov 20 00:48:05 localhost.localdomain automount[22030]: handle_packet:      type = 5
 Nov 20 00:48:05 localhost.localdomain automount[22030]: handle_packet_missing_direct: token 22, name /tests/nfsshare, request pid 22057
 Nov 20 00:48:05 localhost.localdomain automount[22030]: dev_ioctl_send_fail: token = 22
```

Additionally, **ls -l /tests/nfsshare** actually produces the error:

```
 ls: cannot access nfsshare/: No such file or directory
```

How can I fix this issue? As stated before, manual mounting the share works fine.

---

EDIT: as requested, output of `ls -la /etc/auto.nfsshare`

```
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 99 Nov 20 00:25 /etc/auto.nfsshare
```

Comment: could you please show us the output of "ls -la  /etc/auto.nfsshare"?

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro output appended!

Comment: seems ok. How about adding "rpcbind: 192.168.254.105"  in /etc/hosts.allow does it solve it?

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro added your text to /etc/hosts.allow. set selinux to permissive, stopped firewalld via systemctl. still nothing.

Comment: What is the version of NFS by default on both sides?

Comment: mounting it manually shows client uses version 4. server supports 2, 3 and 4.. I think the 2nd log portion I've posted is relevant, but don't know what it means..

Comment: indeed...however out of ideas by now. none of the things I thought it could be.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

Configuration is fine, but directory does not exist, although is seems created.

The solution in my particular case was that the file was an UTF-8 file, which autofs cannot read (that's why you get the Blob message in the logging).

Recreate the file, and make sure it is an ascii file.
After I changed that, everything worked flawlessly.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't encoutered username/password protected NFS share so far.

Anyway, you can make good use of systemd features here (example for a basic NFS share you would want to mount in /tests/nfsshare).

```
192.168.254.105:/srv/nfsshare /tests/nfsshare   nfs users,_netdev,x-systemd.automount  0 0
```